# How to convert JSON Array to HTML select (with checkboxes)?

Tags: javascript, json

I have an array of json objects

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Max"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Bob"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Mike"
    }
]
```

How to convert it to html select (with checkboxes)?

Comment: `JSON.magic(String.toHTML)`

Comment: It was recently renamed `JSON.voodoo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example that might help you:

```
<select name="datas" id="datas"></select>
    <script>

        html = "";
        obj = {
            "1" : "Name",
            "2": "Age",
            "3" : "Gender"
        }
        for(var key in obj) {
            html += "<option value=" + key  + ">" +obj[key] + "</option>"
        }
        document.getElementById("datas").innerHTML = html;

    </script>
```

Hope this helps.

Keep me posted